# How to Display My Original Deck of Cards Java

Tags: java, playing-cards

The shuffled deck will print but the original deck will not, when I use the code below I get this : [Ljava.lang.String;@677327b6 
And its repeated 52 times.

```
public class Deck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] SUITS = {
            "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"
    };

    String[] RANKS = {
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
    };

    // initialising deck
    int n = SUITS.length * RANKS.length;
    String[] deck = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < RANKS.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SUITS.length; j++) {
            deck[SUITS.length * i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];

     System.out.println("Original Deck Of Cards");
     System.out.println(deck);
    }
 }
    // shuffling the cards in the deck
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = i + (int) (Math**strong text**.random() * (n - i));
        String temp = deck[r];
        deck[r] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = temp;
    }
    // printing shuffled deck
    System.out.println("Randomly Shuffled Deck Of Cards");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
     }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < RANKS.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SUITS.length; j++) {
        deck[SUITS.length * i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];

 System.out.println("Original Deck Of Cards");
 System.out.println(deck);
}
```

to

```
System.out.println("Original Deck Of Cards");
for (int i = 0; i < RANKS.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SUITS.length; j++) {
        deck[SUITS.length * i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];
        System.out.println(deck[SUITS.length * i + j]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.toString(deck)` to get string representation of array

Comment: I cannot use Collection classes from the Java Class Library or external libraries when I am implementing this code, is there any other alternatives? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use below loop instead of your Original Deck Of Cards loop:

```
        System.out.println("Original Deck Of Cards");
        for (int i = 0; i < RANKS.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SUITS.length; j++) {
                deck[SUITS.length * i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];

                System.out.println(deck[SUITS.length * i + j]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use Collection classes from the Java Class Library - write your own method. Something like that:

```
private static String deckToString(String[] deck) {
    StringBuilder template = new StringBuilder();
    for (String card : deck) {
       template.append(card).append("\n");
    }
    return template.toString();
}
```

and then print it: `System.out.println(deckToString(deck));`